# Spring ftp configuration is wrong

Tags: java, ftp, spring-integration

I have to poll an ftp location. For testing purpose I have created an ftp site on my machine using IIS manager. It listens at port 21 and is started.

The dependancies are proper for my project

This is the xml configuration for spring ftp

```
<bean id="ftpClientFactory"
    class="org.springframework.integration.ftp.session.DefaultFtpSessionFactory">
    <property name="host" value="localhost"/>
    <property name="port" value="21"/>
    <property name="username" value="ICMAS"/>
    <property name="password" value="kavita12"/>
    <property name="clientMode" value="0"/>
    <property name="fileType" value="2"/>
    <property name="bufferSize" value="100000"/>
</bean>
<int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter id="ftpInbound"
    channel="ftpChannel"
    session-factory="ftpClientFactory"
    charset="UTF-8"
    auto-create-local-directory="true"
    delete-remote-files="true"
    local-filter="compositeFilter"
    remote-directory="c:\ftproot"
    remote-file-separator="\"
    preserve-timestamp="true"
    local-directory="c:\data"
    >
    <int:poller fixed-rate="1000"/>
</int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter>

<int:channel id="ftpChannel"/>
```

The filenamegenerator and the compositefilter are present in my code but havent pated their code here.

My problem is that the local-directory is getting polled instead of the remote-directory. I thought that the files are read from the remote-directory location the go to the filter and if successful will go to the filenamegenerator and be put in the local-directory location. What is wrong with this code???

Please correct me if I am doing something wrong.

Need help on this issue... Please put in your suggessions!!

Comment: Is any more information needed for this question or is any part unclear??

Comment: Hoping to get some suggessions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have resolved this issue.

firstly I needed the filter attribute rather than the local-filter as there is a difference in them.

Secondly and more importantly I have given the romote-directory location as the absolute path. That needs to be relative to the ftp directory mentioned while creating the ftp site.

Thanks. Hope this is useful to someone!!